# laravel backpack CRUD filter by pivot table

Tags: laravel-5, pivot-table, crud, laravel-backpack

here is sources
[subscriber model](http://pastebin.com/prDz6xU2)

### [crud controller](http://pastebin.com/4seRUjqW)

The filters by category is not working in this case.

### could somebody help me with this issue ?

here is a filter code

```
 $this->crud->addFilter([
        'name' => 'category',
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'label' => 'Category'
    ], function () {
        foreach (\App\Models\Category::get() AS $k => $v) {
            $res[$v->id] = $v->name;
        }
        return ($res);
    }, function ($values) {
        $values = json_decode($values);
        unset($values[0]);
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $this->crud->addClause('with', ['Category' => function ($query) use ($value) {
                $query->where('category_id', '=', $value);
            }]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Roman, what error are you getting? What's not working?

Comment: filtering is not working. when I check some value from the dropdown in filter sections.